# Setting color for the legend items of Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am trying to set a color for my elements on the Shield UI Chart legend. I see there are backgroundColor and borderColor, but no color. The same is for the legendItemSettings-
no color property I can set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact there is a color property, however it is part of the

```
 legendItemSettings: {}
```

property and can be refered to as a CSS property rather than a property of the Shield UI
Chart. So you are right, that there is no color property for the chartLegend, however we can adjust the items colors by using the

```
elementStyle:{}
```

property as shown below:

```
chartLegend: {
  legendItemSettings: {
    elementStyle: {
        color: 'red'          
    }
  }
}
```